# Selecting Linear Transformations that are Isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Select Linear transformations that are isomorphisms
>
> A. $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$
>
> B. $T:Fun({1,2,3})\to\mathbb R^3$ defined by
> $T(f(x))=(2f(1)+2f(2)+3f(3),f(1),f(1)+f(2)+f(3))$
>
> C. $T:\mathcal P_3(R)\to\mathbb R^3$ defined by $T(p(x))=(p(0),p(2),p′(−1))$
>
> D. $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(−x−y+z,−x−2y−z,x+y)$
>
> E. $T:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ defined by $T(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$

So, I have this question, I kinda understood how to find them but still confused in some parts. At first, I found the Kernel of the linear-transformations, then if it's not zero it can't be an isomorphism. But if it's zero I'm using dimensional formula.

Therefore, when I used the formula in this question I found that $(D , E)$ are isomorphisms, but I'm not sure about the others. Kinda confused with polynomials and functions. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B. Think of the function $f:\{1,2,3\} \to \mathbb R^3$ as the tuple $(f(1),f(2),f(3))$

How is this different from the the vector $(x,y,z)$ ? It really isn't.  It is just a tuple real numbers.

It might feel more comfortable to say $T(x,y,z) = (2x+2y+3z,x, x+y+z)$

C. The set of polynomials $\mathbb P^3$ is the set of polynomials of degree 3 or less.  i.e. $(ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d).$  This space has 4 dimensions and is being mapped to a 3 dimensional space, and hence has a non-trival kernel.

However, supposing that it wasn't....

We can of the space of polynomials as the tuple $(a,b,c,d)$

$p(0)= d\\
p(1) = a+b+c+d\\
p(2) = 8a+4b+2c+d\\
p'(x) = 3ax^2 + 2bx + c\\
p'(-1) = 3a - 2b + c$

And then you can look to see if the transformation is 1-1 and onto.

Comment: So, I somehow did the calculations and found that A, B, D, and E are Isomorphisms, the method I used is finding if (x,y,z) are equal to zero its Isomorphism. Can you please check it, and if I'm incorrect can you let me know, please.

Comment: A. is not an Isomorphism.  The Transformation maps $\mathbb R^3$ to a single point!